# How can I make my IF statement do the following?

Tags: google-sheets

If I am using all of column A for example,

I want to do this:

IF cell value is between 30-34 then * 1.5, IF cell value is between 35-39 then * 2, IF cell value is between 40-44 then * 2.5???

Answer (score 2):

You need to use nested if statements ...

```
If(and(A1>=30,A1<=34), A1*1.5, if(And(a1>=36,A1<=39),A1*2, if(and(A1>=40,A1<=44),A1*2.5,"")))
```

Paste the above into cell H1 and drag the formula down.

Comment: Thanks, this got me exactly what I wanted!

Comment: If you reverse the lookup order, the ANDs can be eliminated. e.g. `=if(A2>=40, A2*2.5, if(A2>=35, A2*2, If(A2>=30, A2*1.5, "")))` (note `A2>=35` not `A2>=36`)

Answer (score 2):

At some point, nested IF statements become unwieldy and a lookup to hard-coded values or a lookup table is more efficient.

```
=A2*lookup(A2, {0, 30, 35, 40}, {1, 1.5, 2, 2.5})
```

[image]

Comment: Never seen that before, but will use it in future!